# Android: Refresh currently displayed ViewPager fragment tab after entering data in prompt from Main Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I have a floating action button (FAB) in the Main Activity with 4 Fragment tabs under it.

I have a separate dialog prompt for data input when clicking the FAB depending on which tab is displayed.

Now for the first tab, I am able to refresh the contents of the fragment immediately after entering data and clicking OK in the dialog prompt using `Interface`. However for tabs 2-4, I am not able to refresh the data at once after clicking OK in the respective dialog prompt for each of tabs 2-4. I have to click the first tab then go back to the previously displayed tab to be able to refresh the views.

**What I want to do is:**

From second/third/fourth tab, after entering data and clicking the input dialog prompt for the respective tab, the currently displayed tab should immediately update the views inside it based on what I entered in the dialog and saved into the database.

Please note that I am saving the inputs into the database after clicking the OK button in the prompts.

How can I do this? Thank you in advance and I appreciate all your help! :)

Here is my code (I am using interface):

```js
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private PopupListener popupListener;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Your dialog code.
    setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        popupListener.onDialogClick("first_tab"); //"second_tab" for second tab, and so on...
      }
    })
  }

  public void setPopupListener(PopupListener popupListener) {
    this.popupListener = popupListener;
  }

  public interface PopupListener {
    void onDialogClick(String value);
  }
}
```

Code in 2nd tab:

```js
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ((MyActivity) getActivity()).setPopupListener(new MyActivity.PopupListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDialogClick(String value) {
        //After clicking dialog ok button in Activity
        setUserVisibleHint(true, view); // get value from the database here.
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Code to update currently displayed fragment (sample below is for **2nd** **tab**):

```js
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser, final View view) {
  super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
  if (isVisibleToUser) {
    //get data from database and refresh view.
    viewFunds(view) //method is for updating 2nd tab
  }
}
```

Inside OnCreate() of all 4 fragments:

```js
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  setUserVisibleHint(false);
}
```

**First tab code: (added as per comment request)**

```js
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
  ((Main2Activity) getActivity()).setPopupListener(new Main2Activity.PopupListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDialogClick(String value) {
      //After clicking dialog ok button in Activity
      // you will get value here.
      viewBudget(view); //method to updated views inside first tab
    }
  });
}
```

FAB OnClick Listener:

```js
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton_main2);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          int position = tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition();

          switch (position) {
            case 0:

              // first tab is selected

              //Toast.makeText(context,"0",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


              break;
            case 1:
              // second tab is selected
              //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              break;
            case 2:
              // third tab is selected
              //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              UpdateableFragment.showDialog(); //ERROR: non static method onDialogClick cannot be referenced from static context
              break;
            case 3:
              // third tab is selected
              //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"3",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              break;
          }
```

Comment: I am already using `Interface` as mentioned in the question. You mentioned `broadcast`, can you please give more details by adding an answer? Thank you.

Comment: Code for first tab added (see updated question above). Thanks :)

Comment: Inside first fragment, onViewCreated.

Comment: I've already implemented this in all fragments before as advised by the person who gave me the code however it still did not work that is why he advised to add `setUserVisibleHint` but still won't work. I also updated to `public class settings_tab extends Fragment implements Main2Activity.PopupListener` but error occurred: Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method on string 'onDialogClick(String) in PopupListener. How should I proceed?

Comment: Sorry what do you exactly mean by "implement method"?

Comment: Sorry I do not get this since I am just new to android development, can you please add a sample code in the answers? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I believe your problem is that your activity has *one* listener it can invoke on clicking OK on the dialog, but you have *four* fragments. So  only the *one* that's currently registered as the listener will get the callback.

Since your logic is communicating from an Activity down to Fragments, there's no need for a callback here (usually you use callbacks to communicate *from* Fragments *up to* the owning Activity).

So you can replace your interface with an explicit call to the relevant Fragment:

```
// Your dialog code.
setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        figureOutWhichFragmentIsSelectedAndCallExplicitUpdateMethodOnIt();
  }
})
```

Now, that's one option. I don't know what your code or app looks like beyond your sample, but it sounds like the dialog being shown is specific to each Fragment? In which case I think it makes more sense to have the fragment in question show the dialog and handle the interaction itself.

So you could have an interface / base for all of your fragments:

```
public interface UpdateableFragment {
    void showDialog();
}
```

Then implement this interface for each fragment:

```
public TabOneFragment extends Fragment implements UpdateableFragment {
    @Override
    public void showDialog() {
        // Show dialog for tab one data, register listener, save specific data
    }
```

Same idea for the others. Then in your activity it boils down to:

```
myFabButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        UpdateableFragment fragment = getCurrentlySelectedFragment(); // You define this method to return the current fragment
        fragment.showDialog();
    }
}
```

This means 1) the activity has less logic to do to figure out which fragment is selected and which method on it has to be called since it's going through a common interface and 2) your fragments don't have to know what kind of Activity they're attached to (right now each fragment is explicitly casting to `MyActivity` and calling a known method on it, which breaks encapsulation).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @dominicoder, I have studied your answer and the codes provided. I will test it and get back to you should I have questions. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @dominiicoder: Yes you are correct, the dialog shown is specific to each fragment when I click the Main Activity FAB.

Comment: Hi @dominicoder, I implemented your codes. My FAB OnClickListener is a little different since I am using `tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()` then `switch` and `case`. I added your code `UpdateableFragment.showDialog()` in case 2 and I encountered an error _non static method onDialogClick cannot be referenced from static context_. Please see my FAB code in the updated question above. How should I proceed? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I guess the issue is that I have not added this: `UpdateableFragment fragment = getCurrentlySelectedFragment();`. What code do I need to add inside the `getCurrentlySelectedFragment` method?

Comment: That is up to your implementation which is why I left it blank. You have 4 fragments stored somewhere, yes? And you know which tab is currently selected. So you have to write the code that says, based on the currently selected tab index, the currently selected fragment is such-and-such.

Comment: You are correct, I have 4 fragments, can you give high level sample code for _the currently selected fragment is such-and-such_? I have an error in `UpdateableFragment Fragment = settings_tab(); //-->settings_tab is name of 2nd fragment` which says "Method call expected".

Comment: I can't because that's based on your code's logic. If you have member field of the activity for the fragments, then you would say `UpdateableFragment fragment = settings_tab;` (notice no `()` because it's a field, not a method, hence your error).